# Can i use different client certificates for different locations using nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, authentication

I have two different location on my Server:

- server/locationA
- server/locationB

I want to restrict access to these locations using two client certificates certA and certB.

locationA should only be accessible using certA and locationB only by using certB.

until now i did it like this using different ports:

```
server {

  listen 11111 ssl;
  server_name ServerA;

  ssl_certificate server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key server.key;

  ssl_client_certificate certA.crt;
  ssl_verify_client optional;


  location /A {
    if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
      return 403;
    }
    alias /www/data/files/A.html;
  }
}

server {

  listen 22222 ssl;
  server_name ServerB;

  ssl_certificate server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key server.key;

  ssl_client_certificate certB.crt;
  ssl_verify_client optional;


  location /B {
    if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
      return 403;
    }
    alias /www/data/files/B.html;
  }
}
```

my Question now would be is it possible to have both location at the same Port e.g. (server/A and server/B instead of server:11111/A and server:22222/B) ? And how would i need to structure my nginx config to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A certificate applies to the server block, as it has to correspond to the servername.

It's not possible to use a different certificate just for a location.

Different server blocks are however the only thing you need, and you already have that. Just add two server blocks with port 443, use different `server_name`s and their corresponding certificate.

Comment: Do server_names correspond to different domain names or are these nginx/internal specific server names ?

Comment: This is the DNS name the server block should answer to.